# Вывод массива байтов в терминале COM порта

Tags: c, массивы, char, byte

Здравствуйте,

пишу программу на си.
Хочу по uart передать следующую последовательность байтов:
 "0x1F 0x10 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x01"      .
Т.к. типа **byte** в си нет, использую char.

Программа выглядит примерно следующим образом:

```
      char str[6]= {31, 16, 0, 1, 0, 1 };

      printf("%s\n", str);
```

Проблема в том что эту последовательность я вывожу на терминал
последовательного порта и он выводит только 0x1F 0x10, потому что
'0' является символом конца строки, поэтому он думает что строка заканчивается и обрезает остальную часть.

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли вывести на терминал всю строку с нулем вместе, т.е. чтобы ноль не являлся концом строки ?

Использую терминал termite.

Спасибо всем за ответы.

Проблема решена с использованием не массива символов типа
`char` а массива с типом `uint8_t` (аналог `byte` в **си**), которая
находиться в библиотеке **stdint.h** . Код программы:

```
     #include <stdint.h> 

     uint8_t str[6] = {0x1F, 0x10, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01};
     fwrite(str,sizeof(str),1,stdout);
```

Спасибо большое, **gbg**, за помощь.

Comment: Выводите последовательность посимвольно, а не как ASCIIZ-строку.

Comment: @PinkTux, спасибо за ответ, посимвольно у меня почему-то не получилось, выводит ошибку. Может я что-то делаю ни так, но вот эта команда,к примеру, не работает : * printf("%c\n", 'A');*. (компилятором выводиться ошибка)

Comment: Вообще то `uint8_t`  это `typedef unsigned char uint8_t`.  ваш КО

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первое. Тип байтов в C есть и называется `uint8_t`. Живет в `stdint.h`

Второе. Используйте `fwrite(str,sizeof(str),1,stdout);`

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, все заработало. Теперь буду иметь в виду, что `uint8_t` это аналог `byte`. Еще раз спасибо, *gbg*.